# Charge conjugation operator effect on electromagnetic potential

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, charge-conjugation

The charge conjugation operator acts on a complex scalar field as follows:

$$ \mathcal{C} \phi(x) \mathcal{C}^{-1} = \alpha \phi(x)^{\dagger}$$

and by assuming that the interaction of the field with an electromagnetic potential $A_{\mu}$ is invariant under said transformation then we should arrive at:

$$ \mathcal{C} A_{\mu} \mathcal{C}^{-1} = - A_{\mu}    \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space (1) $$

and subsequently conclude that for a photonic state:

$$ \mathcal{C} | \mathbf{k} , r \rangle = - | \mathbf{k} , r \rangle \space \space\space \space\space \space (2) $$

How are we supposed to achieve results $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving equation (1):
This is a little more general than only showing for a scalar field, but it is also a little more hand-wavey. If the interaction density for your Lagrangian (or Hamiltonian) is invariant under charge conjugation that means that:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}\mathcal{L}_{int}\mathcal{C}^{-1} = \mathcal{L}_{int}
\end{equation}
We take the electromagnetic coupling to be of the form,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{int}=\mathcal{j}_\mu(x) A^\mu(x)
\end{equation}
Under charge conjugation $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{j}_\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}=-\mathcal{j}_\mu(x)$, which agrees with our intuition of "switching the label of positive and negative charges". This means for the theory to be invariant,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}\mathcal{L}_{int}\mathcal{C}^{-1} &= \mathcal{L}_{int}\\ \mathcal{C}\mathcal{j}_\mu(x)A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1} &= \mathcal{j}_\mu(x)A^\mu(x)\\
\mathcal{C}\mathcal{j}_\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1} &= \mathcal{j}_\mu(x)A^\mu(x)\\
-\mathcal{j}_\mu\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1} &= \mathcal{j}_\mu(x)A^\mu(x)\\
\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1} &= -A^\mu(x)
\end{align}

Specifically for a complex scalar field, the interaction is slightly more complicated because it is non-linear. From minimal coupling, the interaction term looks like (dropping the position argument),
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{int}=-ie((\partial_\mu \phi^*)\phi-\phi^*(\partial_\mu\phi)) A^\mu+e^2\phi^*\phi A^\mu A_\mu
\end{equation}

Now you can apply the charge conjugation and track each term and see what eigenvalues for $A^\mu$ make it consistent. I'll show for the final term,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}(e^2\phi^*\phi A^\mu A_\mu)\mathcal{C}^{-1}&=e^2\mathcal{C}\phi^*\mathcal{C}^{-1}\mathcal{C}\phi\mathcal{C}^{-1} \mathcal{C}A^\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1} \mathcal{C}A_\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1}\\
&=e^2\alpha^*\phi\alpha\phi^*(\mathcal{C}A^\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1} )(\mathcal{C}A_\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1})\\
&=e^2\phi^*\phi(\mathcal{C}A^\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1} )(\mathcal{C}A_\mu\mathcal{C}^{-1})\\
\end{align}
The final step is because $|\alpha|^2=1$, and $\lbrack\phi^*(\textbf{x},0),\phi(\textbf{x},0) \rbrack=0$. You can follow similar steps for the other two terms, except now the terms no longer have vanishing commutators. Once you get all three terms into this form you can see what transformation properties $A^\mu$ must satisfy for charge conjugation invariance.

Deriving equation (2): Write out your field operator acting on the vacuum state

\begin{align}
A^\mu(x)|\Omega\rangle &= \int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\big(\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})a_r(\textbf{k}) + \epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})a^\dagger_r(\textbf{k})\big)|\Omega\rangle\\
&= \int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})a^\dagger_r(\textbf{k})|\Omega\rangle\\
&= \int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})|\textbf{k},r\rangle
\end{align}

Now apply the charge conjugation operator,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)|\Omega\rangle &= \mathcal{C}\int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})|\textbf{k},r\rangle\\
\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}\mathcal{C}|\Omega\rangle &= \int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})\mathcal{C}|\textbf{k},r\rangle\\
\end{align}
The charge conjugation operator commutes with $\epsilon^\mu(\textbf{k})$ because it only acts on operators and states, the polarization vector is a c-number quantity not an operator. Next we define the vacuum to be even under charge conjugation, and use your equation (1),
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}A^\mu(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}|\Omega\rangle&=-A^\mu(x)|\Omega\rangle
\end{align}
Now combining all of the above,
\begin{align}
-A^\mu(x)|\Omega\rangle&=\int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})\mathcal{C}|\textbf{k},r\rangle\\
-\int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})|\textbf{k},r\rangle&=\int \frac{\text{d}^4k}{2\omega_k}\epsilon^\mu_r(\textbf{k})\mathcal{C}|\textbf{k},r\rangle\\
\mathcal{C}|\textbf{k},r\rangle&=-|\textbf{k},r\rangle
\end{align}
You can follow very similar steps for parity, and for different fields. For example to show that fermions and anti-fermions have opposite parity. Although admittedly that involves more steps and keeping track of a lot more minus signs.

Comment: I still don't understand how you arrived at the result of equation $(1)$

Comment: That's because I missed that you asked for equation (1) to be derived. I can add it

Comment: I would appreciate if you could do that

Comment: I added an argument based on a general current, you could work it out more explicitly for the defined complex scalar field, and its defined interaction term. It would amount to similar steps, but I think it is less general and hides some of the physical intuition. I am side stepping a little bit though.

Comment: I updated it again to specifically address the complex scalar field as my general argument doesn't actually hold for that case