# Charge conjugation of Fourier modes

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, charge-conjugation

Considering the charge conjugation operator acting on a complex scalar field:

$$ \mathcal{C} \phi(x) \mathcal{C}^{-1} = \alpha \phi^{\dagger}(x) $$

By doing a Fourier expansion of the complex scalar field $\phi(x)$ as follows:

$$ \phi(x) = \sum_{k} ( a(k) e^{ikx} + b^{\dagger}(k) e^{-ikx} ) $$

where:

$$ \sum_{k} = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2 \pi)^3 2 E_k} $$

and:

$$ E_k = \sqrt{k^2+m^2} , \hspace{0,5cm} [ a(k),a^{\dagger}(k')] = [ b(k),b^{\dagger}(k')] = (2 \pi)^3 2 E_k \delta_{kk'}   $$

and the other commutation relations being zero, how can we show that:

$$ \mathcal{C} a(k) \mathcal{C}^{-1} = \alpha b(k) , \hspace{0,5cm} \mathcal{C} b(k) \mathcal{C}^{-1} = \alpha^* a(k) $$

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/765358/2451

Comment: @flippiefanus $\alpha$ is a phase factor.

Answer (score 0):

You say you know that
$$\mathcal{C}\phi(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}=\alpha\phi^{\dagger}(x)$$
So, I assume you also know that
$$\mathcal{C}\pi(x)\mathcal{C}^{-1}=\alpha\pi^{\dagger}(x)$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the conjugate momentum to $\phi(x)$. Inverting the above relations yields
$$\phi(x)=\mathcal{C}^{-1}\Big(\alpha\phi^{\dagger}(x)\Big)\mathcal{C}=\alpha^*
\mathcal{C}^{-1}\phi^{\dagger}(x)\mathcal{C}
\\
\pi(x)=\mathcal{C}^{-1}\Big(\alpha\phi^{\dagger}(x)\Big)\mathcal{C}=\alpha^*
\mathcal{C}^{-1}\pi^{\dagger}(x)\mathcal{C}$$

The creation operators, then, satisfy
$$a_{\vec{p}}=\int d^3\vec{x}\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}
e^{-ip\cdot x}\frac{1}{2}
\Big(\phi(x)+i\pi^{\dagger}(x)\Big)$$

Perhaps now you can show the properties you wish to prove. I hope this helps. I haven't done the calculation myself, but this seems the way to go. If there are any questions, please comment.

Comment: Nevermind, I already found the answer, thank you anyways.